# SSIS Foreach Loop with specific flat files

Tags: foreach, ssis, flat-file

I am trying to import different csv files from a folder containing different csv file types.
So I need to filter my foreach loop with the starting flatfile name.
I only want to process files starting with MyFileType_1*.csv and not the others in the same folder.
Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What do you have so far? If you already have a foreach loop you can use `Files` input in the Collection node to define the filter you need. What else do you need? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: I have diferrent kind of files in my folder, I just want to process in my package files starting with ASpecificName*.csv to exclude other files. I am not able to specify MyfileName*.csv in the colection enumerator or I don't know the way to do it, Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not able? Just replace the `*.*` in the inputfield for `Files:` in `Collection` with `ASpecificName*.csv`!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for-each container can specify which files to read as Ocaso is saying. In the Variable mappings tab in the for-each container you can there set which variable you want to save the files found. Then you can use this variable as the connection string to a flat file connection.
[image: Set which files to read]
[image: Set variable mappings]
[image: Set connection string]

Answer (score 0):

[Nighty_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244815/244935) is correct, but just for the sake of completeness it is worth mentioning that to set the `ConnectionString` in a Flat File Connection you must use a variable of **package-level scope** in the expression (in his case `@[User::v_FilePath]`). This is because the connection itself is package level. This might feel a bit unintuitive... or ugly... it is.