# filter filename from folder that contains a specific text in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am trying to move some files from one folder to another, and i Need to evaluate if a file name contains certain text then only we need to move those files.

for example , i have following files in a folder.

```
abcd_takeme_fdsljker.txt
abcd_file_fdsljker.txt
abcd_takeme_fdsljsdfker.txt
abcd_filetk_fdsljker.txt
abcd_takeme_fdsljssker.txt
```

from the above I want to pick files which has text `"takeme"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Foreach Loop with specific flat files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243893/ssis-foreach-loop-with-specific-flat-files)

Comment: @TabAlleman i don't think this is a duplicate. It is more general than the question u provided. The OP is asking for any method and have not specified the `Foreach loop` method. It can be achieved using script task or other component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using For each loop container

1. You have to add a for-each loop container to loop over files in a specific directory.
2. Choose the follow expression as a filename:

   `*takeme*`
3. Map the filename to a variable
4. Add a dataflow task inside the for each loop to transfer files
5. use the filename variable as a source

*you can follow the detailed article at:*

- http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx

if you want to add multiple filter follow my answer at:

- [How to add multiple file extensions to the Files: input field in the Foreach loop container SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195171/how-to-add-multiple-file-extensions-to-the-files-input-field-in-the-foreach-loo/43198065#43198065)

### Using a script task

or you can achieve this using a script task with a similar code: (i used VB.Net)

```
Public Sub Main()

    For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\New Folder\", "*takeme*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim filename As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile)

        IO.File.Copy(strFile, "D:\New Folder\" & filename)

    Next

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```